# How do i get a value from java file dialog and pass it to a variable?

Tags: java, swing

Currently I'm having trouble to pass an event driven file dialog to a variable

This is how the program should work , User presses a file path then it will be save in File object for further manipulation

Here's the code

```
public class FileChooser {

 private String filePath;      

  public FileChooser(){
          prepareGUI();
  }

 private void prepareGUI(){
  mainFrame = new Frame("Naufal File Chooser");
  mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
  mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
  mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
        System.exit(0);
     }        
  });    
  headerLabel = new Label();
  headerLabel.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
  statusLabel = new Label();        
  statusLabel.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
  statusLabel.setSize(350,100);

  controlPanel = new Panel();
  controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
  mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
  mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true); 


 }


  public void showFileDialogDemo(){
     final FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(mainFrame,"Select file");
      Button showFileDialogButton = new Button("Open File");
      showFileDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           fileDialog.setVisible(true);
           statusLabel.setText("File Selected :" 
           + fileDialog.getDirectory() + fileDialog.getFile());
                //Here is where I should get the value, I tried set and get and as well as using return at the bottom both return null
                // I'm trying to use setFilePath to store the file
           setFilePath(fileDialog.getDirectory() + fileDialog.getFile());
             }
          });
       controlPanel.add(showFileDialogButton);
       mainFrame.setVisible(true);  
  }

   public void setFilePath(String file) {
       this.filePath = file;
   }

   public String getFilePath() {
       return filePath;
   }

    }
```

In the main.java

```
public class FileMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileChooser fileChosen = new FileChooser();
        fileChosen.showFileDialogDemo();
        // Here it is always return null
        String fileName = fileChosen.getFilePath();
        System.out.println(fileName); // Always return null even before I click the file path.
        File myFile = new File(fileName);

   }
}
```

What is the logical to get a value from an event driven object?

Comment: My bad it is supposed to be FileChoser

Comment: And your showFileDialogDemo() method?

Comment: where the method `getFilePath()`?

Comment: It is just a get and set methods, for clarity I don't put it

Comment: @Satya since you are asking, I already modified the code to not confuse future readers

Comment: It seems that `showFileDialogButton` is never used? Or is the given code incomplete?

Comment: @MarcodeZeeuw It is used, basically in the fileChooser there are frames and stuff thats why in the Constructor there is a prepareGUI function.

Comment: What you could do/try is set `final FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(mainFrame,"Select file");` inside the actionPerformed listener, before the setVisible ofc. Then it also doesn't have to be final anymore.

Comment: There seems to be an extended portion of your code (the GUI) which you're not providing

Comment: @MarcodeZeeuw Tried it but keep saying fileName is null because it doesn't wait for the event to finish instead it goes to the next line and show me nullPointerException. The real question how do i block an event method before it even goes to the next line of codes?

Comment: @MadProgrammer here is the full code for GUI, check the updated version

Comment: Yeah true. The problem for us is that we don't see al of the code, but what you can do is make the dialog on which you put `showFileDialogButton` modal (setting modal can't be done on Frame). That will block the code until the modal-window has returned.

Comment: @MarcodeZeeuw I already posted all the codes for the GUI, the question is how do i achieve my goal? can you guide me and answer the question So i could accept it

Comment: Have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: mainFrame is now a Dialog with a null-parent. The modality-type makes sure the code is blocked once mainFrame is shown.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileChooser fileChosen = new FileChooser();
    fileChosen.showFileDialogDemo();

    String fileName = fileChosen.getFilePath();
    // This is called as soon as mainFrame is hidden
    System.out.println(fileName);
}

public static class FileChooser {

    private String filePath;
    // This is now a Dialog instead of a frame
    private Dialog mainFrame;

    public FileChooser() {
        prepareGUI();
    }

    private void prepareGUI() {
        // APPLICATION_MODAL makes sure the code is blocked once mainFrame is shown.
        mainFrame = new Dialog(null, "Naufal File Chooser", Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        mainFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void showFileDialogDemo() {
        Button showFileDialogButton = new Button("Open File");
        showFileDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(mainFrame, "Select file");
                fileDialog.setVisible(true);
                setFilePath(fileDialog.getDirectory() + fileDialog.getFile());
                // This is to make sure the code resumes where it was blocked
                mainFrame.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        mainFrame.add(showFileDialogButton);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setFilePath(String file) {
        this.filePath = file;
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why extend from `Frame`, that's just confusing the matter

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, I agree, but the problem is that Dialog needs a parent-window. Which is why I stated that it needs optimisation. Imo the real problem lies within the call of the println in the main. Instead, this call should be somewhere within `FileChooser` or `mainFrame`. What's missing is the exact usecase of the program to come with a real solution.

Comment: You can get away with `null` for the parent

Comment: Yeah you're right, with some constructors you can. I'll edit the answer

Comment: This answer is perfect, So everytime when I implement APPLICATION_MODAL and mainFrame is showing it is blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Use thread, because you don't know how much the user take to finish the mainframe section. We need to regularly check - is the mainframe is gone. Then we will get the value otherwise we get null.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FileMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final FileChooser fileChosen = new FileChooser();
        fileChosen.showFileDialogDemo();
        // Here it is always return null 
        javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                 @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        if(fileChosen.mainFrame.isVisible() == false){
                            String fileName = fileChosen.getFilePath();
                        System.out.println("\nIn main: "+fileName); // Always return null even before I click the file path.
                        File myFile = new File(fileName);
                        System.out.println(fileName);
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                   }
                });
                t.start();
        }
   }



import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FileDialog;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class FileChooser {
    Frame mainFrame;
    Label headerLabel;
    Label statusLabel;
    Panel controlPanel;

 private String filePath;      


  public FileChooser(){
          prepareGUI();
  }

 private void prepareGUI(){
  mainFrame = new Frame("Naufal File Chooser");
  mainFrame.setSize(400,400);
  mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
  mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
        System.exit(0);
     }        
  });    
  headerLabel = new Label();
  headerLabel.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
  statusLabel = new Label();        
  statusLabel.setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
  statusLabel.setSize(350,100);

  controlPanel = new Panel();
  controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  mainFrame.add(headerLabel);
  mainFrame.add(controlPanel);
  mainFrame.add(statusLabel);
  mainFrame.setVisible(true); 


 }


  public void showFileDialogDemo(){
     final FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(mainFrame,"Select file");
      Button showFileDialogButton = new Button("Open File");
      showFileDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           fileDialog.setVisible(true);
           statusLabel.setText("File Selected :" 
           + fileDialog.getDirectory() + fileDialog.getFile());
                //Here is where I should get the value, I tried set and get and as well as using return at the bottom both return null
                // I'm trying to use setFilePath to store the file
           setFilePath(fileDialog.getDirectory() + fileDialog.getFile());
           mainFrame.setVisible(false);
             }
          });
       controlPanel.add(showFileDialogButton);

  }

   public void setFilePath(String file) {
       this.filePath = file;
       System.out.println(file);
   }

   public String getFilePath() {
       return filePath;
   }
}
```

Comment: Or just use a modal `Dialog` which was designed for just this case

Comment: if (fileChosen.mainFrame.isVisible) has an error , not really sure what is the problem

Comment: What is the error ?  if you need to use , then  use`if (fileChosen.mainFrame.isVisible())` .you don't use `()` after isVisible